# Displaying a Rectangle in LineChart

Tags: charts, javafx

How can I display a Rectangle object in javafx.scene.chart.LineChart? Adding data like this to the chart series doesn't seem to help

```
new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(point.getX(), point.getY(), 
        new Rectangle(point.getX(), point.getY(), 10, 10) {{
            setFill(Color.BLACK);
        }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3d argument of the XYChart.Data constructor is an extra value not a node value :)